# Destination Action is not excecuted

Tags: outsystems

I have the button"Accept and Print" the screen, which allows to print the screens and allows to submit the form.

[image]

When I hit the button the print screen opnes and after I print, the action associated with it is not executed . But stays on the same page.

Can anyone tell me if I have done anything wrong. Any help is greatly apprecitaed thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `return false;`

It's stoping the propagation of the click event and preventing the call to the screen action from being executed.